# insertMany error output is duplicated BulkWriteError (Server Localhost - Client Shell)

Tags: mongodb

Most of the posts here discuss this problem when using Mongoose. In my case, I'm using the shell, running the server locally, and for some reason facing the same thing. The result is the expected: only the first document of the array is inserted and the second generates the error. Hence, the third one would be created only if I define {ordered: false}. But I would like to understand where this duplicated output comes from because eventually, I could face side effects. Any suggestion?

**COLLECTION**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60265ab7b8a433e266896a0a"),
    "name" : "Apple",
    "revenue" : "1000"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c"),
    "name" : "Alibaba",
    "revenue" : "1800"
}
```

**QUERY**

```
db.getCollection('companies').insertMany([{name:"Amazon", revenue:"2500"}, {_id: ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c"), name:"Alibaba", revenue:"1800"}, {name:"Google", revenue:"1500"}])
```

**SHELL OUTPUT**

```
uncaught exception: BulkWriteError({
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 1,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: config.companies index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('60265b04b8a433e266896a0c') }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c"),
                "name" : "Alibaba",
                "revenue" : "1800"
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
}) :
BulkWriteError({
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 1,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: config.companies index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('60265b04b8a433e266896a0c') }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c"),
                "name" : "Alibaba",
                "revenue" : "1800"
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
BulkWriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:367:48
BulkWriteResult/this.toError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:332:24
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1186:23
DBCollection.prototype.insertMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:326:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Provide *complete*  output if you are specifically asking about it.

Comment: This is the complete output! It doesn't return anything else besides that. What do you mean by complete output?

Comment: The complete output is https://gist.github.com/p-mongo/d8528cad150866b8c319e476715a91f1. You are missing the trailer and since you omitted the trailer, one wonders if you also omitted something in the header.

Comment: @D.SM, the file you sent me has the same code I posted here under shell output. The only difference is that I separated the output from the query that triggers the output. Which header did you mean? I can add the information here. There is no extra code. I just executed this query after initializing the shell on the terminal.

Comment: The insert error is expected as you are trying to insert a document with an already existing `_id`: `{_id: ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c"), name:"Alibaba", revenue:"1800"}`

Comment: @prasad_ That is on purpose. I expected the error. I would like to know why the query is printing the error twice as output. I thought it could be an outcome from Retryable Writes (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/), but I didn't set anything. I merely started the client and executed the query.

Comment: I tried your query, and get the same error. If you try with `insert` and `insertOne` and try to insert just one document only (`_id: ObjectId("60265b04b8a433e266896a0c")`), the error formats are different... I dont know why.

Comment: @prasad_ hopefully it will not provoke major side effects. For example, I use Robo3t to access my DB, and if I execute this query there, it adds the document Amazon (the first on the array) twice! I was wondering if it could provoke some bigger problem on my code. I'm gonna keep the question open and maybe someone, sometime, pops up with new information. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: My apologies, your post does include the trailer which I didn't see originally. If you make any edit I'll retract the downvote.

Comment: Fine @D.SM! I did some edition in case you want to revert that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a peculiarity of the MongoDB shell (which, supposedly, was developed as an internal tool for MongoDB server developers and isn't actually designed for end users, despite many end users using it and it being extensively referenced in MongoDB documentation).

If you try some other queries (like inserting two documents with the same `_id`) you'll get different error reporting, and those errors aren't marked *uncaught exceptions*. So it seems that bulk write errors aren't handled correctly by the shell, i.e., this is likely a shell bug.

I don't see what side effects an error report can produce.

Comment: I understood the concept of the bug. My thought was: if I'm receiving the error message twice, maybe the query ran also twice. Running the query on Robo3T, another interface for the client side, it added the first document of the array twice, what corroborates with my thought! I'll observe, but I don't think it would cause major problems...

Comment: That's a separate question (query being executed twice, or unexpected documents being inserted).